# Is there a way I can use wireless projectors?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, libreoffice, presentation, projector

I can connect to the projector but I can't seem to find a way to output my presentations to the projector. I'm using LibreOffice and Ubuntu 10.04. I do quite a few presentations at my work and I am using the VGA output and a wire connected to the projector. Most of the projectors are now being updated with wireless units. YIKES!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)